# When calling out django n python prompt

Tags: python, django, pydev

After downloading and unzipping Django, when i get to calling it in the python prompt it wont let me. I type import  django and it spits out no module named django??
Any suugestions would be great.

Comment: Did you follow the installation instructions?

Comment: With the same Python installation that you're now trying to import it in?

Comment: Do you have more than one python installation? From the install log, where is the django code put in?

Comment: sussed it, unzip here unzip there, my patience is thin in this area

Answer (score 2):

This is the procedure you need to make sure its done:

1. Unzip the Django folder. say its in `c:\users\userid\downloads` or in `/home/user/downloads`
2. Open terminal, get into the django folder dir.
3. Run `$ python setup.py install`

you are done.

try this. and it should work

```
$python
>>> import django
>>>
```

Or else if you have `pip` installed.. Just run `$ pip install django` and it will download and install automatically.